DBT External Table Databricks
I get csv files dropped into Azure Blob storage daily and set up a Databricks volume to access these files.  I ingest these files with dbt using:
select *
from read_files('<path/to/volume/folder>')

Is there a way to create this path as a source so I can use a command similar to:
select *
from {{ source('source_name', 'table_name') }}

I set up a source with the following data:
version: 2

sources:
  - name: source_name
    tables:
      - name: table_name
        external:
          location: '<path/to/volume/folder>'
          file_format: csv'

When I run:
select *
from {{ source('source_name', 'table_name') }}

The compiled query is:
select *
from catalog_name.schema_name.table_name

I get an error because this table does not exist in the Databricks catalog as it is an external blob storage folder.

Make sure you are creating a metastore database that points to the external data source only.

Instead of using a source macro that creates a catalog.schema.table namespace, you could create a custom macro that iterates through the sources, finds the match for the source name and table name and loads the argument in the read_files function. This way you can use it as close to dbt source.
read_source macro:
    {% macro read_source(source_name, table_name) %}
        {% set source_nodes = graph.sources.values() if graph.sources else [] %}

        {% for node in source_nodes %}
            {% if node.source_name == source_name and node.name == table_name %}
                {%- set external = node.external if node.external else {} -%}
                {%- set location = external.location -%}
                {%- set format = external.format -%}

      read_files("{{location}}", 
                            format => "{{ format }}")
                {% break %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endmacro %}

sources.yml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: source_name
    tables:
      - name: table_name
        external:
          location: '<path/to/volume/folder>'
          file_format: csv'

dbt model:
select *
from {{ read_source('source_name', 'table_name') }}

